# Passing state through props in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding passing a state variable into a React function.  Take the following code as an example:

```
export interface INumberProps {
    mynumber: number,
    show: boolean
}

var updateNumber = function() {

}

export function GetNumber(props: INumberProps) {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>Enter a number: </label>
            <input type="text" value={props.mynumber} />
            <button onClick={updateNumber} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And then from the main page, something like this:

```
{this.state.showNumberQuery &&
    <GetNumber mynumber={this.state.mynumber} />
}
```

Effectively, what I'm trying to do is pass a state variable into a function and simply have the function change the state by virtue of changing the variable.  I'm aware the functions can't *explicitly* change the state, but would something like this work implicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of [lifted state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). `GetNumber` child component cannot modify the state directly, it should be provided with setter callback:

```
<GetNumber
  mynumber={this.state.mynumber}
  updateNumber={mynumber => { this.setState({ mynumber }) }}
/>
```

Which can be used as `props.updateNumber(42)` inside a child.

Comment: Thanks - should that in fact be "updateNumber={this.state.mynumber ... " or was that intentional?  If so, how would React know where to take mynumber from?

Comment: `myNumber` would be passed while calling the function. Read the last line of the answer again `props.updateNumber(42)`.

Comment: @SmileyDev No, it shouldn't. `updateNumber` is a function. Check the linked article for the explanation how this approach works.